# Virtualenv installing to local instead of virtual

Tags: python, odoo, virtualenv

I am trying to install OpenERP server into a virtual enviroment that I created for that. I created the virtual using

```
mkvirtualenv openerp_rev5054
```

On said virtual enviroment I use

```
> (openerp_rev5054)user@machine:python setup.py install --record files.txt
```

And gives that I have no permission, and if I install it with root access, it goes directly into my python local install. Here is a sample of my files.txt with the location of all the files installed.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/import_xml.rng
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/release.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/loglevels.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/release.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/PKG-INFO
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/pooler.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/loglevels.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/pooler.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/exceptions.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.saas_3-py2.7.egg/openerp/exceptions.py
```

I have a couple of others already installed and the procedure was the same so I see no reason why this one should behave different in any way. Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

Comment: This is likely to be a bug in OpenERP. Could you point us at the source repo for the specific package?

Comment: Sure i can, but i don't think it is a bug related to OpenERP, since i have other 2 virtualenvs with openerp. The first one i installed is with the trunk branch and correctly installed into the virtualenv but this revision and another with branch 7.0 gives the same issue both install into /usr/local/lib.

Comment: I am using revision 5054 of the trunk branch since in revision 5055 they removed the run-tests functionality of the oe script.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with pip rather than setup.py. I hear that pip plays nicer with virtual environments.

Comment: Uhmm, that's the issue, i am installing a specific revision of the code here for testing purposes, if i use pip install won't install the latest version available of the code?

Comment: @Berenlut, you can tell pip to install a specific version, including giving it a URL use in contacting revision control.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your virtualenv is activated. If it is, you should have an environment variable `$VIRTUAL_ENV` that has the value of the root directory of the virtualenv. Or, more commonly, you'll see a change in your shell prompt.

If it is activated, make sure that your `$PATH` is correct, perhaps something else has come along and changed it. `which python` should point at a python inside your virtualenv bin directory.

If you have an old version of virtualenv, ensure you're using `--no-site-packages`

Comment: The question shows an appropriately modified prompt.

Comment: Indeed, i activated it using workon of vitualenvwrapper. In regard of version of virtualenv i am using 1.7.1.2, wich i think it comes with --no-site-packages by default. And the variable $VIRTUAL_ENV has value of /home/user/Envs/virtual_env_name.

Comment: @Berenlut ...one thing Andrew asked for you _didn't_ disclose, though, is the output from `which python`. (Actually, `type python` would be better, revealing if there are any shell functions or such wrapping the interpreter, whereas `which` is an external command and can't see into shell internals).

Comment: My bad, output of type python points to the virtual enviroment location python is /home/cllamach/Envs/openerp7.0/bin/python, likewise which points to the same location.